# embedding the fonts at runtime?

Tags: apache-flex, fonts, runtime, embed

i want to embed some of the system fonts on client machine in my flex app at run time there is way to load the fonts swf at runtime but it is not suitable cause of some security issues.

is there any way to embed fonts at run time in my flex app?

regards

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can load fonts at runtime... or should I say you can [load style sheets at run time](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=styles_10.html). Just set your font styles in an external style sheet and load it at runtime. Since there is an override chain, you can even keep all the rest of your styles hard coded in if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

I embedded fonts to my mobile app with flex. But I added a folder with fonts in my asset folder. It's not at runtime but it's a way to embed your font. Then you can add the font in CSS:

```
<fx:Style>
        @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
        @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";

        @font-face{
            src:url('/assets/font/Cocon-Regular_0.otf');
            font-family: Cocon;
        }
</fx:Style>
```

After this steps I could use the Cocon font.

Hope this could help you.

Comment: i know how to embed the assets in the app i don't want to keep assets a the size of app increases very much i just want to get fonts at runtime

Comment: An otf-file isn't that big. I guess you'll have to find out what kind of fonts there are on the current system itself and use one of those.